# Int cannot be converted to bytes using java

Tags: java, byte

I am trying to convert my integer value to bytes which is to unsigned bytes. I heard that java bytes only provide until 127. Then I tried to reedit my code

This is my code after editing:

```
Integer servo1 = 5117;
Byte data1;
data1 = (((byte)servo1) >> 6 & (byte)0xFF);
```

What if I want to add a byte inside a byte array is it possible?

This is the code:

```
send = {(byte)0xE1, data1, data2, data3};
```

Now the error is showing `Integer cannot be converted to Byte` Can I know how to solve this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is not quite right. You want to cast the whole expression on the right side to `byte` if you want to assign it to that variable type. So use this:

```
    Integer servo1 = 5117;
    Byte data1;
    data1 = (byte) ((servo1) >> 6 & 0xFF);
```

You may be interested in the Java article on type conversions (specifically the section on integer promotions): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Comment: Just to confirm will my value changed? Example 0xFF should be 255 if its converted to integer. So the value still will show 255 or -255 something. Because sometime for instance if i use 0xC6 i should get 198 but sometimes i get -57 if i am not mistaken. Btw thanks for you answer @Kon it helped me to solve my problem for now ...

Comment: Any integer value cast to a byte will rollover. It will never have a value greater than that max value defined for `byte`. Make sure you test thoroughly what you're doing. This is pretty messy in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is `**Integer** cannot be converted to **Byte**`. It is because explicit conversion between numerical values cannot be done by their **Wrapper classes**. By `(byte)servo1` you are trying to convert a `Integer` *i.e. a wrapper class of int* into `byte` *i.e. a primitive type*.

Consider the following example :

```
Long l = 10000000L;
Integer i = (int) l;     // Long cannot be converted to int
Byte b = (byte) i;       // Integer cannot be converted to byte
```

To do conversion between wrapper classes you should use methods provided by them :

```
Long l = 10000000L;
Integer i = l.intValue();
Byte b = i.byteValue();
```

And to do conversion between primitive primitive type you can do it explicitly as you were trying to do with wrapper classes :

```
long l = 1000000L;
int i = (int) l;
byte b = (byte) b;
```

That means your conversion would have worked if you have used primitive types :

```
int servo1 = 5117;
byte data1;
data1 = (((byte)servo1) >> 6 & (byte)0xFF);
```

Or if you have used correct method to convert wrapper classes you were using :

```
Integer servo1 = 5117;
Byte data1;
data1 = (byte)(servo1.byteValue() >> 6 & (byte) 0xFF);
```

Comment: @raaj5671 You should ask one question in one post. By the way what is the type of `send`. And if it is `Byte[]` it will not give any error and will work fine.

Comment: I am sorry @afalex its under Byte data type

Comment: I hope you understand why you were getting error while converting. @raaj5671 , And another thing is you don't need to add `@afzalex` to notify a person on whose post you are commenting, he will be notified automatically.